# Zero-inflated negative binomial regression on gut microbiome data in R

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

thank you guys so much in advance!

I got a table, containing the information of gut microbial composition of different groups, that is, the count data of different bacteria in each sample of different groups. However, over-dispersion and excess zero are observed.

To better compare the difference of different groups, I thouhgt zero-inflated negative binomial regression should be performed. So I followed the guide from UCLA. [UCLA statistical consulting](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/zinb/)

The original data is like this, but much longer with more `SampleID`, `temperature` and `OTUNUM`:

```
SampleID temperature OTUNUM abundance
1   D_913   22  1   6
2   D_913   22  2   0
3   D_913   22  3   0
4   D_913   22  4   6
5   D_913   22  5   0
6   D_913   22  6   0
7   D_913   22  7   0
8   D_913   22  8   204
9   D_913   22  9   0
10  D_913   22  10  1076
11  D_913   22  11  28
12  D_913   22  12  1250
```

and I have got the `res` after get confidence intervals for the parameters and the exponentiated parameters using bootstrapping, like this:

```
summary(res)
          Length Class      Mode     
t0          436  -none-     numeric  
t         43600  -none-     numeric  
R             1  -none-     numeric  
data          4  data.frame list     
seed        626  -none-     numeric  
statistic     1  -none-     function 
sim           1  -none-     character
call          6  -none-     call     
stype         1  -none-     character
strata     7276  -none-     numeric  
weights    7276  -none-     numeric
```

Sadly, when estimating the basic parameter with percentile and bias adjusted CIs, I met an error.

```
parms <- t(sapply(c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), function(i) {
  out <- boot.ci(res, index = c(i, i + 1), type = c("perc", "bca"))
  with(out, c(Est = t0, pLL = percent[4], pUL = percent[5],
              bcaLL = bca[4], bcaUL = bca[5]))
}))
```

the error is:

```
Error in bca.ci(boot.out, conf, index[1L], L = L, t = t.o, t0 = t0.o,  : 
  estimated adjustment 'a' is NA
In addition: Warning message:
In norm.inter(t, alpha) :
 Error in bca.ci(boot.out, conf, index[1L], L = L, t = t.o, t0 = t0.o,  : 
  estimated adjustment 'a' is NA 
7.
stop("estimated adjustment 'a' is NA") 
6.
bca.ci(boot.out, conf, index[1L], L = L, t = t.o, t0 = t0.o, 
    h = h, hdot = hdot, hinv = hinv, ...) 
5.
boot.ci(res, index = c(i, i + 1), type = c("perc", "bca")) 
4.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
3.
lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) 
2.
sapply(c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), function(i) {
    out <- boot.ci(res, index = c(i, i + 1), type = c("perc", 
        "bca"))
    with(out, c(Est = t0, pLL = percent[4], pUL = percent[5],  ... 
1.
t(sapply(c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), function(i) {
    out <- boot.ci(res, index = c(i, i + 1), type = c("perc", 
        "bca"))
    with(out, c(Est = t0, pLL = percent[4], pUL = percent[5],  ...
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem? If you need the original data and more information or you know how to upload my original data, don't hesitate to message me, please! Thank you so much in advance!

Best withes,
Jiqiu

Comment: `res$t` contains the estimates from the bootstrap resamples. What does `summary(res$t)` tell you? Also, why do you have 436 parameters (including the exponentiated ones)?

Comment: Firstly, this is the output of  ```summary(res$t)```: ```V1              V2               V3                 V4               V5                  V6               V7          
Min.   :2.908   Min.   :0.1339   Min.   :-1.94171   Min.   :0.2280   Min.   :-1905.932   Min.   :0.7234   Min.   :-2.32544  
 1st Qu.:3.279   1st Qu.:0.1376   1st Qu.:-0.97534   1st Qu.:0.2484   1st Qu.: -128.791   1st Qu.:1.0748   1st Qu.:-0.04847  ```, and much more is shown. Secondly, maybe because there are so many bacteria?

Comment: I think you should step back from the bootstrapping and focus on the model first. I'd say you have an unreasonable number of parameters. You also don't describe a mixed effects model and your data looks like you should use one.